# Change TextField border color if props is required in a react/material ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

If there is required then show TextField border color is red and once entered value then show NO RED border.
Please click on the link to see images.

[Entered Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ96V.png)

[Without Value with Required field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iq8S.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can put a condition on the `TextField`s `error` like this
`<TextField variant="outlined" label="Amount" name="amount' helperText={touched.amount ? errors.amount : ''} error={touched.amount && Boolean(errors.amount)} fullWidth />`

Comment: Is it possible to share working example?

Comment: Create first a codesandbox